# I want to change the font on part of my String variable (textview) with a font located in assets

Tags: android, fonts

I have textview which contains a string that i want a specific part of it to be red and use a different font from the rest of the text this is what i've tried

in the onCreate method i put a different font on the whole textview

```
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf");
mn.setTypeface(tf);
```

and after that Si is part of a for loop and when a case is matched i want to change the font

```
Si+="<font face='RobotoCondensed-Bold'  color='#8B2121'><b>"+SiArray[0]+"</b></font>";

    mn.setText(Html.fromHtml(Si));
    mn.setTextSize(19.5f);
```

so RobotoCondensed-Bold is a font that i have in assets folder in my android project how to use that font instead of the regular Ariel....etc...etc...

Comment: how did you solve this?